# BASH - Search file for pattern then append that line

Tags: bash

I've seen a few examples on how to search for a pattern then append a specific string to that line. What I'm trying to accomplish is a bit different, I think. I'm writing a simple script that will take an argument, search a file for a string and if found append the argument(s) to the end of the line where the string was found. I'd call this script by doing:

$bash- ./myscript.sh arg1 [arg2] ...

For the code I have something like:

```
for ARGS in $*
do
    gawk '{a[NR]=$0}/<patter to be found>/{a[NR]=a[NR] $ARGS}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' $ORIGFILE > $DESTFILE
    cp $DESTFILE $ORIGFILE
done
```

The problem is that the single quotes won't expand the variable and I haven't found the right syntax to accomplish so. Either nothing expands or the "$0" expands and that throws a syntax error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `$*`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass shell variables to awk using this syntax:

```
awk -v arg0="$0" -v arg1="$1" '{ print arg0, arg1, $0 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sed`. It seems easier than `awk` for this task.

```
sed -i "s/<pattern>/$*/" $ORIGFILE
```

**Notes**

1. No need for loop. `$*` captures all the arguments
2. No need to create another file and copy it back. `-i` will do in-place replace
3. Enclose expression within double quote `"` to expand shell variables